# Drag module restricted in YUI

Tags: javascript, html, css, yui

Have created an interactive drag module in YUI 3.17.2 and implemented this same in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6mdwcmgt/3/) to check the module created using dd-drag module, but I could not drag my box.

```
YUI().use('dd-drag', function(Y) {
    var dd = new Y.DD.Drag({
        node: '#place'
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console readout gave a clue:

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

You're loading your fiddle via https, but the YUI script is via http. Just chop off the s in your address bar and you're golden :)

Comment: if the client url contains 's',how to chop that down :) ?

Comment: Well then you'd have to host it on the client server instead of pulling it from a CDN. But to get your fiddle working, that's what you gotta do :)

Comment: How come :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598060/drag-module-created-using-yui-yahoo-user-interface-library-getting-restricte